# How to manage DB transactions in Kohana / PHP elegantly

Tags: php, database, transactions, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm new to Kohana but come from a Spring/Java background.

In Spring I'm used to all service methods automatically having DB transactions applied to them. I just tag the method to indicate whether it only needs a read transaction or read/write.

What do people do in this regard in Kohana? A new app I'm working with doesn't have transactions except manually in a few places where they know it's necessary. To me this seems a bit risky, it's easy to overlook some transactional consistency requirement, it was always nice to have that globally enforced in Spring.

Comment: what does your kohana documentation says about it? and as far as I know, its a fork of codeigniter framework, so you can check codeigniter's documentation if its of any help.

Comment: Kohana doesn't do this. It should, though, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I deal with it:

1. Create a base class for all service method classes:

   ```
   abstract class Base
   {

       public function __call($method,$arguments)
       {
               // Start transaction here
               echo 'start';

               try
               {                    
                   call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $arguments);

                   // Commit
                   echo ' commit';
               }
               catch ($e)
               {
                   // Roll back
               }                       
       }

   }
   ```
2. Create a child class with all "protected" functions:

   ```
   class Member extends Base
   {
           protected function test()
           {
               echo 'test';
           }
   }
   ```
3. Call service method:

   ```
   $member = new Member();

   $member->test();
   ```

It will display: "start test commit"

The trick here is you will have to use "protected" for all your functions, if not it will no longer run (it will call the "test" function directly, not through __call().

Comment: Son, what a great solution you suggest, it's almost like you're working on the same problem as me here. :)   One point though, spring transactions allow us to set them as Read Only or Read/Write (useful for innodb tables for example). I might suggest a naming scheme such as [functioname_RW] to indicate if the txn should be started as read only or read-write.

Comment: Note that this solution will fail when a service method calls die or exit - you need to register a shutdown function to handle such a case.

Answer (score 4):

In Kohana transactions need to be done manually, there is no way to do it like in Spring.
Below you can find some ways how to deal with it:
Using `Database` methods:

```
$db = Database::instance();
$db->begin();

try
{
    // do your stuff here

    $db->commit();
}
catch(Database_Exception $e)
{
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Using Query Builder:

```
DB::query('START TRANSACTION');
// do your stuff here

If (no errors)
    DB::query('COMMIT');
else
    DB::query('ROLLBACK');
```

Comment: If PHP had `finally`, this could be written more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Kohana module (inspired by Spring) that makes using transactions a lot easier:

https://github.com/brazzy/kohana-transactional

After adding the module, you can just add

```
public $_transactional = true;
```

to the controller, and all actions are automatically executed inside a transaction, which is rolled back when the action fails with an exception. This seemed to me to be the most useful implementation, as having a separate service layer doesn't seem to be common in PHP projects.

I may eventually implement support for read-only transactions (if it's possible to do in a vendor-independant way).

Answer (score 1):

Do it by Hand and for your individual situations:

```
$db = Database::instance();
$db->begin();
try{
    // do your stuff
    $db->commit();
}catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e){
    // ceep care WHAT you catch
    $db->rollback();
}catch(Exception $e){
    // and catch whatever exceptions too
    // or your rollback is blown in the wind
    $db->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```